# What's the difference between Android 2.2 Froyo and Android v1.6 Donut?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 1.6-donut

I am really new to Android and I barely know about it.

I now want to buy an [Archos](http://archos.com) device that should be an alternative to iPod and its size should be like the iPod.

I saw there are different Archos devices.
I am doubting between the Internet tablet (Android 2.2 Froyo) [43](http://www.archos.com/products/ta/archos_43it/index.html?country=us&lang=en) and the [48](http://www.archos.com/products/ta/archos_48it/index.html?country=us&lang=en)/[5](http://www.archos.com/products/ta/archos_5it/index.html?country=us&lang=en) (Android v1.6 Donut).

What is a better OS? What is more advanced?

My desires:

Mandatory:

- Audio/Video playback (flash)
- Wifi (Gmail, GCal sync)
- eBook reader
- Pocket size (iPod size or so)

Desired but not mandatory:

- Voice mic (for potential web conversation, and recording)
- Video/photo camera
- FM receiver

BTW, I just saw Android 3.1 is out, is it possible to update these devices with the new OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are HUGE differences between 1.6 and 2.2. 1.6 is also a pretty old version of android. Flash is only available for 2.2 and later, so if you have to have flash then you need to go with 2.2. But the archos 43 does not have an FM receiver, the 48 has a receiver, and transmitter.

The UI had big improvements in 2.2 compared to 1.6. The ability to install apps on an external sdcard is also available on 2.2, but I don't think you will really need that as the 48 says it has 500GB (that seems like a lot for a device like that...). I have also read that it is possible to install froyo on the 48.

3.x is currently only available on select devices as they have to "partner" with google in order to have access to Honeycomb (3.x). So I wouldn't expect to see an update on these devcies anytime soon for 3.x.

Comment: +1 I see. So bottom line, according to my desires listed above, what device is best for me (I don't care what brand or even OS, just a device that will give me the above features, anything in the market)? In fact, I would surely buy the iPod Touch 4, but I heard that transferring media from PC must be thru iTunes, this is evil and I cannot accept this. Any recommendations on any device that suits me would be really welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Really, product recommendations are off topic, which is why I tried to stay away from that in the answer. you will have to take the differences between the devices you are looking at and see what features are best for your.

Answer (score 2):

Android 2.2 also introduced a better just-in-time compiler, so the system runs quite a bit faster than before. Features list [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2-highlights.html).